# HTML 5 Validation fails on Javascript src urls with & at the end

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have java script function like below in my html code, after I included this it seems to be breaking the HTML 5 validation on the page. Does anyone has any idea on how to fix this or by pass it ?

Please Note: changing `&` to `&amp;` will not work as it will break that external js which I am not in control.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/display/js/ads.js?4768&1436&300&600"></script>
```

Error i get is

```
& did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as &amp;.)
```

Comment: You have a typo in your script tag `javascript"`, look at it.

Comment: Separate issue, your script tag should be this: `<script src="http://example.com/display/js/ads.js?4768&1436&300&600"></script>` without the `javascript"` in it.

Comment: @t.niese I believe OP is talking about html validation of the page ...such as w3c validator

Comment: corrected script type as i have highlighted its not the main concern or the problem of this question

Comment: if it's really critical to get page source validated could write the scipt tag into the page using `document.write` or create a script tag using js and append it to head

Comment: @charlietfl yes you are right. I'm a bit exhausted.

Comment: @mahen3d Are you really sure you can't use `&amp;`. Did you try it? IMHO (which could be wrong as i'm tired)   `src="http://example.com/display/js/ads.js?4768&amp;1436&amp;300&amp;600"`  should work as the `src` would still always be `http://example.com/display/js/ads.js?4768&1436&300&600` no matter if it is accessed by script or if it is send to server as request (the replacing of `&amp;` should happen at parsing time)

Comment: no script wont work because i can see in thier js code they decode it using "&" not using "&amp;"

Comment: @mahen3d as I said i'm sure that `&amp;` is converted by the browser to `&` before any script is executed and before the request is send to the server. You can check the console and the networktab with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tbov7o04/),  so did proof that it won't work or is it just an assumption?

Comment: no as i said in the js it self they are decoding these with "&" not with "&amp;" , it doesnt work